# Access, Update and Run an R script from another R script

Tags: r, gsub, rscript

I would like to access, update and run an R script from another R script. Specifically, I would like to create a loop that reads in the lines of another R script in order to update some variable names by adding increments of 1 to each of them. Once the variables have been updated, I would like to run the R script.

Currently my code for this is as follows:

```
for (i in 1:n) {
x <- readLines("Mscript0.R") 
y <- gsub(paste0("Mtrain",i),paste0("Mtrain",i+1), x) 
cat(y, file="Mscript0.R", sep="\n") 
source("Mscript0.R")
}
```

Please note that the string "Mtrain" in the source script takes on various different forms such as:

```
Mtrain4 <- read.csv("Mtrain4.csv",header=T,sep=",")
s <- Mtrain4$Weight
```

Any Ideas?

Thanks

Comment: I'd love to help! What is your question?

Comment: this seems like a bad programming practice.  Instead of updating variable names by brute read and write, why not make them arguments to whatever routine you're running repeatedly?